# Using Yacc and Lex in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, yacc, lex

I have read that Xcode 4 (and I suppose previous versions) have built in support for Yacc and Lex which I am just learning about. I'm trying to set up a simple project to test them out but as I'm new to Xcode and Yacc/Lex I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do it.

Can anyone recommend a helpful guide or tutorial for using Yacc/Lex in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 4):

Having written an interpreted language in Xcode I have found the following tutorials and references useful.

http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/

http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/

http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/

Here is some information about the Yacc support in Xcode: [Integrating Bison/Flex/Yacc into XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296758/integrating-bison-flex-yacc-into-xcode)

Best of luck to you!

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful. Thanks!