# how to get xcode code sense/autocomplete working with lex/yacc input files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, yacc, lex, codesense

Is there any way to get proper syntax highlighting, autocompletion, etc. for objective-C code in lex and yacc input files with XCode?  Specifically, I'm even using .lm and .ym files, and XCode 4.2.  XCode sort of recognizes them, since it builds them properly and formats them in a monospace font, but no help coding at all.  Code sense is working properly in normal source files.

I've looked around and I did find the XCCodeSenseAllowAutoCompletionInPlainFiles user default, which helps a little, but it's still not anywhere close to real code sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating Bison/Flex/Yacc into XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296758/integrating-bison-flex-yacc-into-xcode)