# Objective-C and Bison warning: stray `@'

Tags: objective-c, bison, yacc

When I generate my parser with bison, I obtain this warning:

```
warning: stray `@'
```

But that is because I have some legal Objective-C code containing `@`, for instance this is one of the rules having the warning:

```
file : axiom production_rule_list    { NSLog(@"file"); }
     ;
```

Is there any risk to use `@` in the code? If not, how to tell bison that it is a legitimate use of `@`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=711554

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not during gcc compiling, but when I generate the parser with bison...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating Bison/Flex/Yacc into XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296758/integrating-bison-flex-yacc-into-xcode)

Comment: @robmayoff My problem is just the bison warning, not the integration of Flex and Bison into Xcode.

Comment: @Zaphod But the bison warning is resolved with the information in the linked post. You just have to rename your yacc file to use the `.ym` extension.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe My files are already named with the `.ym` extension, and the warning is still here because I do not use Xcode to compile it but a command line script. My question, by the way, never mentioned Xcode but `bison`. So the integration of `flex` and `bison` in Xcode (right click an so on) is not my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation in [Actions - Bison 2.7](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Actions.html), it appears that the code between the curly braces is expected to be C code.  As such I doubt that you can use objective-c constructs there.

However you could create an external C function to do the work for you like:

```
Logit(char* message)
{
  NSLog(@"%s",message);
}
```

And use that in the Bison action

```
file : axiom production_rule_list    { Logit("file"); }
     ;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for this information. I will stick to C within the curly braces. But it's only too bad, because putting Objectve-C is working in the generated parser...

Comment: But the `NSLog` still expects an `NSString` as format, so it should be  `NSLog(@"%s",message)`.

Comment: This answer is wrong--you can use objective-c inside the braces. The message is just a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The message is just a warning.  You can ignore it.  If you're using Xcode, it won't even show you the warning in its Issue Navigator.

Rename your Bison input file to have a `.ym` extension instead of a `.y` extension.  That tells Xcode that it's a grammar with Objective-C actions.

Comment: Definitely the best answer if true

Comment: My files are named `.ym` but I launch bison by a script: `bison --defines=system.define.h -o system.yacc.m system.ym` not using Xcode.

Comment: Ok. Well. But how does Xcode tell bison it's Ocjective-C? There's no bison command line I know for that, is there? Or does Xcode use its own bison?

Comment: There's no special Bison flag.  It just warns about the `@` but passes it through anyway.  Xcode doesn't do anything special; the `.ym` extension just tells it to compile the output of Bison as Objective-C instead of as C.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suppress the warning, you can use a `#define AT @`.

The code in the braces is just copied, apart from replacing the $… sequences with the code to give the relevant token. This appears to work fine with Objective-C, although if you're using ARC, you might need to do some digging (or just add extra blocks (in the C sense)) to make sure that objects are freed as soon as possible.